# Instantiating Vue components using only string

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a string saved as a variable in javascript that contains both the `<template>` and `<script>` tags that could be saved into single file components in vue. Here is an example:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        {{myVar}}
        <button @click = "change(1)">Increment</button>
        <button @click = "change(-1)">Decrement</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    data(){
        var randomVar = Math.round(10*Math.random());
        return {
            myVar: randomVar
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.change(12);
    },
    methods:{
        change(num){
            this.myVar += num;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Is there a way to instantiate said string as a vue component without having to save it as a single file component or separating the data, methods and other lifecycle hooks?

Answer (score 1):

The [HttpVueLoader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader) can load `.vue` files directly in the browser - you can look at the source code and try to modify it to accept the string directly instead of fetching it from an URL.

Additionally, you may want to take a look at the [Client-Side Vue](https://github.com/justinwash/Client-Side-Vue) project - it avoids the building step for SFC so you can use your `.vue` components directly in the browser.